# Cypress : Uploading File with given directory path

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to upload a xlsx file using `fixture` and what I want is to automate the process of finding file, select the file from file management (finder) without prompting the finder and manually choose the file.

Is there anyway to make cypress to do all steps by its own?

here is my code:

```js
 cy.fixture('fileName', 'binary').then((fileContent) => {
      cy.get('input[type=file]')
        .upload(
          {
            fileContent,
            fileName: 'fileName',
            mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            encoding: 'utf-8',
          },
          { subjectType: 'input' }
        )
```

Comment: What happens with `.upload()`? It looks like a custom command.

Comment: From the options `{ subjectType: 'input' }` it looks like it might be a variation of `.attachFile()` from cypress-file-upload.